# MongoDB: Restore documents from backup shard

Tags: json, mongodb, backup, restore

I accidentally deleted some documents from our production database and want to restore them. So, I downloaded a backup shard from MongoDB cloud. I would like to re-add just the deleted documents without restoring the entire database. One suggestion was that I download the documents as a JSON file and upload that JSON file to the production db. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

How can I run the backup shard, download the backup documents as a JSON file, and then upload them back to the production db?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/index.html)?

> That is, if restoring documents to an existing database and collection
> and existing documents have the same value _id field as the
> to-be-restored documents, mongorestore will not overwrite those
> documents.

So, unless you specify option `--drop` mongorestore will restore only the missing documents - this is the default.

In order to run a shard as stand-alone have a look at [Perform Maintenance on Replica Set Members](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-maintence-on-replica-set-members/index.html). Then you can use `mongodump` to get the dump from it.

Comment: Thanks. What I ended up doing was I ran the backup shard on localhost, downloaded the documents into a json file in Mongo Compass, and then simply uploaded the json file into the production db also in Mongo Compass.